# Get next element that is not necessarily a sibling & no class

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how do I find the first occurring element of a certain type after a given element ID? The desired element may or may not be the element immediately after.

The aim of the function below is to hide the first occurring element of type 'select' after the radio button.

```
function showDropDown(radioButtonElem) {
    if(document.getElementById(radioButtonElem.id).checked) {
        /*$(Get next <select> element after radioButtonElem.id).css("display", "none");*/
    }
}

<input type="radio" name="radioButtonGroup" value="sfn" id="sfn" onclick="showDropDown(this);">
<select id="myDropDown">...</select>
```

My understanding of the 'next()' function is that it only finds elements of the same type. I may be wrong; if I am please explain how to use it to solve my problem.

EDIT:
Thanks for feedback all. Based on your input, I thought this would work, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

```
<script>
  function showDropDown(radioButtonElem)
    {
      if(radioButtonElem.checked)
    {
      $(radioButtonElem).nextAll('select').first().css('display', 'none');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: [http://api.jquery.com/closest/](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) if select is not a sibling

Comment: You are correct, and .next isn't what you need. This question has been asked many times before, but there are many differing situations where it is used, so it may be difficult to find one that matches your situation. The sample you gave shows the select as being a sibling, and you say it's not, so it's going to be difficult for us to find a duplicate for you. Why are you doing `document.getElementById(radioButtonElem.id).checked` instead of `radioButtonElem.checked`? it seems a bit redundant.

Comment: do you mean "not necessarily the _following_ sibling", i.e. it will be a sibling, but there might be intervening elements.

Comment: [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) takes a selector so you could do `.next('select')` if it's the _immediately following sibling_.

Comment: @andyb no, that's exactly the point - `.next()` only considers the _very next_ sibling, optionally filtered.  To look at _all_ following siblings you need `.nextAll`

Comment: @Alnitak yeah, I wasn't paying attention to the question, only the code

Answer (score 1):

If the required element is a sibling, just not necessarily the *immediately following* sibling, you can use `.nextAll()` followed by `.first()`

```
$(this).nextAll('select').first()
```

Also - you have jQuery - you should use it for the event handling too:

```
function showDropDown(ev) {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).nextAll('select').first().hide();
    }
}

$(':radio').on('click', showDropDown);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/RsrwV/

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://blog.awonsa.com/jquery-get-next-element-that-is-not-hidden-or-not-display-none-displaynone/) or use below

```
var getNextTD = $('table.listview').nextAll('td').not('[class]').first();
```